# How to assert something conforms to a type without a function?

Tags: typescript

I want to check to see if an object I create conforms to a certain interface but I also want to leave the original type untouched.

I know I can achieve this using an immediately invoked function expression like so...

```
interface MustHaveThingy {
  thingy: any;
}

const originalType = (function<T extends MustHaveThingy>(obj: T) {return obj;})({
  thingy: 'something',
  somethingElse: 'this is part of the type',
});
```

> The type of `originalType` is typed as `{thingy: string; somethingElse: string;}` but it still conforms to the interface `MustHaveThingy`.

...but it's kind of ugly. Is there any way I can achieve the above without the immediately invoked function expression?

What I'm looking for is the whole—`T extends SomeOtherType` where the actual type of `T` is inferred but `T` must conform to `SomeOtherType`—but without the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `as` in a separate statement.

```cs
interface MustHaveThingy {
   thingy: any;
}

const originalType = {
  thingy: 'something',
  somethingElse: 'this is part of the type',
};

originalType as MustHaveThingy; // <- assertion
```

Removing `thingy: 'something'` line gives:

> foo.ts(9,1): error TS2352: Type '{ somethingElse: string; }' cannot be converted to type 'MustHaveThingy'.
>    Property 'thingy' is missing in type '{ somethingElse: string; }'.

Comment: That works! I didn't think of that. Do you know of any way to do with that doesn't emit the assertion statement to javascript?